# onclick event: refresh page before append HTML script

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a button like this:

```
<button onclick="buttonMovieEvent('123')">Watch</button>
```

My purpose is when I click that button, it'll call the `buttonMovieEvent('123')` function where it makes the page refresh, move to a hash, e.g: `http://example.com/#123`, then append HTML script to show the video

My code:

```
function buttonMovieEvent(videoId){
  var hash = "#" + videoId;
  window.location.href += hash;
  location.reload();
  ...
  // build script tag
  var script = "<h3>Watching Movie:<br /></h3><video id=\"" + tag_id + "\" class=\"vjs-matrix video-js vjs-big-play-centered\" controls preload=\"auto\" width=\"1024\" height=\"768\" poster=\"" + poster + "\" data-setup='{}'><source src=\"" + src1 + "\" type='video/mp4'><source src=\"" + src2 + "\" type='video/webm'><p class=\"vjs-no-js\">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that<a href=\"http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/\" target=\"_blank\">supports HTML5 video</a></p></video>";

  $("#movie_show").append(script);
  eventController(tag_id);
}
```

But whenever I click the button, the page refresh and also remove the `<video>` tag so no video appear

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Script after the reload Command won't get executed anymore.

Comment: Why do you need to reload the page ? You can append the `<video>` and scroll to the hash using something like `document.getElementById(tag_id).scrollIntoView();`

Comment: @Dominik so any suggestion for me? I want to refresh the page and then append the script to show the video

Comment: Can you explain why the page HAS to be refreshed before the whole video thing? Since it complicates any solution. So if there isn't a good reason to refresh, i'd be favourable to just not refresh.

Comment: @Shilly since I use `VideoJs` as my playback, but anytime I play the video the second time (by press the button) while it is not finished yet, the console show a warning `VIDEOJS: WARN: Player is already initialised. Options will not be applied`. I already searched for this problem but nothing clear yet. So I think that I need to refresh the page and append script again

Comment: You'll have to show the code you use to operate videojs then. The issue you describe sounds like you're reinitializing the video player wrongly or are not resetting it or something. Kinda a classic XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

After you reload a Page, all Javascript which was supposed to be executed after the reload will not get executed anymore.

You need to run the Javascript `onPageLoad` if you want it to be run after the redirect. Maybe you can check the current location `onPageLoad` and if it contains a hash you want to run the rest of your Javascript code? It depends on what you want to achieve.

If you are just using `location.reload()` to get to some point of the page just use `document.getElementById(tag_id).scrollIntoView();` instead - no page refresh required.